# SharePoint Microsoft word online sorry we ran into a problem opening this pdf

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

I uploaded number of pdf files on SharePoint 2013 library. I have already installed web apps, few pdf files are get opening online. Few are causing error 'sorry we ran into a problem opening this pdf'. I down loaded the file on local computer is working fine.
[image]

Can anyone please confirm me how I can resolve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using a Xerox high-capacity scanner / printer device to scan the documents to PDF. Change the option to PDF/A.

Refer to: https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/793/sharepoint-file-doesnt-have-a-preview-word-online-ran-into-a-problem-opening-this-pdf.aspx

Comment: I am not using Xerox high-capacity scanner / printer device to scan the documents to pdf. I am using webapps on SharePoint to open the pdf in ms  word. I am just faing above issues just 3-4  pdf other are working fine.

Comment: Compare the non-working file with the working file, see if there is any difference.

Comment: I'm glad that you have found the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue we had remote event receiver which would copy the file in different location, In our development environment I realized that two users were using the same login and their was a conflict and this gave rise to this issue. I was able to resolve the issue by checking out the item and then discarding the checkout.
May not be a valid solution but I checked OWA servers and SP WFE and APP server logs in vain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the encryption algorithm. AES128 worked, while AES256 gave the error.